# How to increase the values in the select statement dynamically each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to break date span into quarter of the year. I'm using the below query in main query but as the maximum value reached in the cross apply statement I'm not getting the latest quarter's from the select statement. How to increase the number dynamically in the Values of the select statement. I suppose to get 2022Q2, 2022Q3 and currently its 2022Q4 but the query stopped at 2022Q1 because the Values in the select statement is 12 maximum.

```sql
Select CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(QQ,n,'2019-01-01')) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Q' + DATENAME(qq,DATEADD(QQ,n,'3000-12-31')) as Year_Quarter
from(
SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(QQ,'2019-01-01','2999-12-31')) n
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) rc(n)) as x
order by 1
```

```
2019Q1
2019Q2
2019Q3
2019Q4
2020Q1
2020Q2
2020Q3
2020Q4
2021Q1
2021Q2
2021Q3
2021Q4
2022Q1
```

I tried adding the numbers to the Values then getting

```sql
Select CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(QQ,n,'2019-01-01')) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Q' + DATENAME(qq,DATEADD(QQ,n,'3000-12-31')) as Year_Quarter
from(
SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(QQ,'2019-01-01','2999-12-31')) n
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)) rc(n)) as x
order by 1
```

I want the Values in the inner select to add dynamically to get the current quarter.

```
2019Q1
2019Q2
2019Q3
2019Q4
2020Q1
2020Q2
2020Q3
2020Q4
2021Q1
2021Q2
2021Q3
2021Q4
2022Q1
2022Q2
2022Q3
2022Q4
```

Comment: Why not just have a calendar table?

Comment: Otherwise, what you actually want here is known as a "tally".

Comment: any reason you're going to '3000-12-31' but then only using a subset of the values? you can create a recursive CTE to get a list of quarters between two dates and then use just those values?

Comment: @RickyTillson for an open ended date I'm using 3000-12-31, I'm using cross apply in the main query like this
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(QQ,PLAN_START_DATE,PLAN_END_DATE)) n
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) rc(n)
) x

Comment: sorry, I'm still not understanding why you'd go to 3000-12-31 when you then want to only have data up to the current quarter? you're arbitrarily restricting it with the VALUES 0-14/15/16/whatever when instead you can completely alter how you define your date range to only ever get the period you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me it could be as simple as

```
Select YYYYQQ = datename(YEAR,D)+'Q'+datename(QUARTER,D)
 From ( Select Top 500 D=dateadd(QUARTER,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),'2019-01-01')
          From master..spt_values n1
      ) A
 Where D<=getdate()
```

**Results**

```
YYYYQQ
2019Q1
2019Q2
2019Q3
2019Q4
2020Q1
2020Q2
2020Q3
2020Q4
2021Q1
2021Q2
2021Q3
2021Q4
2022Q1
2022Q2
2022Q3
2022Q4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join two value tables

This always displays the most recent 16 quarters

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(4), (YEAR(GETDATE()) - j.n)) + 'Q' + CONVERT(varchar(1), q.n) as quarter
FROM
 (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS j(n)
 CROSS JOIN
 (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS q(n)
WHERE
    (j.n > 0 OR q.n <= DATEPART(q, GETDATE())) AND
    (j.n < 4 OR q.n >  DATEPART(q, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY j.n DESC, q.n ASC
```

Here I use `j(n)` as year offset that I subtract from the current year to get the last 4 years up the the current one.

The calculated year is then converted to a varchar and concatenated with `'Q'` and the quarter. Note that the year is not hard-coded, so that the query dynamically returns all the quarters from the last four years.

Output created on 2023-01-01:

```
2019Q2
2019Q3
2019Q4
2020Q1
2020Q2
2020Q3
2020Q4
2021Q1
2021Q2
2021Q3
2021Q4
2022Q1
2022Q2
2022Q3
2022Q4
2023Q1
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I run the in Jan 2023 I'll get the 2023Q1?

Comment: You never explained what the query should exactly return. I revised it to suppress future quarters. But it is still not clear what the first quarter should be. Do you always want 16 quarters or always start with Q1?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, use a Tally. An inline one would look like this:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(QUARTER,'20190101','29991231'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
SELECT DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101'),
       CONCAT(YEAR(DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101')),'Q',DATEPART(QUARTER,DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101')))
FROM Tally T;
```

If you wanted to create a function, then you could create it and use it something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@End bigint, @StartAtOne bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @StartAtOne = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@End)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
GO

SELECT DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101'),
       CONCAT(YEAR(DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101')),'Q',DATEPART(QUARTER,DATEADD(QUARTER,T.I, '20190101')))
FROM fn.Tally(DATEDIFF(QUARTER,'20190101','29991231'),0) T;
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want it to go from a fixed start date to a dynamic end date and no further. This code works by getting a hardcoded @StartDate, works out the end of the last quarter to have finished, it then uses a recursive CTE to iterate over dates adding 1 quarter every time, and some string manipulation to get the formatting correct. Once GETDATE() moves into a new quarter the CTE will return a 17th value without having to change the code.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @LastQuarterEndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

WITH recCTE
AS (
    SELECT ConCat(DATEPART(YYYY, @StartDate), 'Q', DATEPART(QQ, @StartDate)) AS DateQuarter, @StartDate AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(YYYY, DATEADD(QQ, 1, recCTE.Date)), 'Q', DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, 1, recCTE.Date))),
           DATEADD(QQ, 1, recCTE.Date)
    FROM recCTE
    WHERE recCTE.Date < @LastQuarterEndDate
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE;
```

Comment: You type `YYYY`, why not `YEAR`? Using abbreviations like `D` and `QQ` can be misleading because you can't do that with, say, `W`. But no excuse for typing four Ys instead of the word it represents. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to build a sequence by replicating the number of quarters and then splitting, calculating the year and quarter number based on the row_number:

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE(),
        @s date = '20190101';

DECLARE @q int  = DATEPART(QUARTER, @d),
        @y int  = YEAR(@d) - YEAR(@s);

SELECT d, q = CONCAT(YEAR(d),'Q',r+IIF(r=0,4,0)) 
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(QUARTER, r-1, @s), r%4
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',',(4*@y)+@q-1),',')) y(r)) z(d,r);
```

Output:

| d | q |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019Q1 |
| 2019-04-01 | 2019Q2 |
| 2019-07-01 | 2019Q3 |
| 2019-10-01 | 2019Q4 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020Q1 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020Q2 |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020Q3 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2020Q4 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021Q1 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021Q2 |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021Q3 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021Q4 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022Q1 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022Q2 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022Q3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022Q4 |

Working example in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_P6gCYN_), including showing what the behavior will be in 2023.